# Command line "no matches found: connexion[swagger-ui]"

Tags: swagger-ui

Able to install connexion, but cannot install swagger-ui. How can I fix this?

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 4):

You can install it by using quotes

`pip install "connexion[swagger-ui]"`